# Using the Euro symbol in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, currency

I using the price in [Euro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro) in JavaScript:

```
var currency = '\u20AC';
Total Sum = Sum in Euro
```

When I try to use in PHP mail, the Euro symbol appears differently. I used the following command:

```
$mail_body_reply=Sum from Javascript
mail($email, $subject_reply, $mail_body_reply, $header_reply);
```

What is the way to make it act the same in PHP and JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add encoding to the mail header, like described in [a comment to documentation for function mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php#86537).

The right encoding is probably [ISO/IEC 8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15).